# Prolog check if list is part of a sequence

Tags: list, prolog, sequence

My task is to define a predicate which checks if a given list is a part of a sequence. The predicate has three members. The first two lists are the beginning of the sequence. Every other element L(N + 2), N >= 0 is concatenation of L(N) and the reversed L(N + 1). I have to check if the third argument is being part of the sequence.

```
my-append([], L, L).
my-append([H|T], L, [H|R]) :- my-append(T, L, R).

list-len([], 0).
list-len([_|T], N) :- list-len(T, N1), N is N1 + 1.

my-reverse([], []).
my-reverse([H|T], R) :- my-reverse(T, R1), my-append(R1, [H], R).

compare-list([], []).
compare-list([H1|A], [H2|B]) :- H1 =:= H2, compare-list(A, B).

fib-list(A, B, C) :-
    my-reverse(B, B1),
    list-len(A, LenA),
    list-len(B1, LenB1),
    my-append(A, B1, C1),
    list-len(C, LenC),
    list-len(C1, LenC1),
    LenC1 =:= LenA + LenB1,
    (
        (LenC > LenC1, !);
        (LenC =:= LenC1, compare-list(C1, C));
        (LenC < LenC1, fib-list(B, C1, C))
    ).
```

And those are some examples:

```
fib-list([1, 2], [4, 3], [4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]). % result is true
fib-list([1, 2], [4, 3], [4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]). % result is true
fib-list([1, 2], [4, 3], [4, 3, 4, 3, 2]). % result is true
```

Example sequence with L1 = [1] and L2 = [2]; L3 = [1, 2]; 
L4 = L2 + reversed(L3) = [2, 2, 1]; L5 = L3 + reversed(L4) = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2]

Results expected:

```
fib-list([1], [2], [1, 2]). % true
fib-list([1], [2], [2, 2, 1]). % true
fib-list([1, 2], [4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]). % true
```

The problem is that the result from the second and the third test is true and I don't have an idea why.

Comment: *Every other element L(N + 2), N >= 0 is concatenation of L(N) and the reversed L(N + 1)* - I'm unclear as to the meaning of this statement, and how it relates to the arguments. Could you clarify? I think it means `[1,2], [4,3]` --> `[1,3,2,4]` but that isn't aligning with your example, so I've got it wrong.

Comment: Do you mean Arg1 + Rev(Arg2) must be the beginning of Rev(Arg3)?

Comment: What's the point in defining widely available library predicates like `reverse/2` instead of using the ones that are already there?

Comment: Please add more sample cases. Also document which result you expect.

Comment: @lurker : my-append(A, B1, C1); where B1 is  created with my-reverse(B, B1)

Comment: Is there a reason you're rewriting the standard libraries, `reverse/2`, `length/2`, and `append/3`? Also, you don't need `compare-list/2`. To check if two lists `A` and `B` are the same, you can just use `A = B` (they unify), or `A == B` (they are the same).

Comment: @lurker the reason is that I'm preparing for an exam where I would not be able to use existing ones :D

Comment: Why do you expect `fib-list([1, 2], [4, 3], [4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]).` to be true?

Comment: @lurker the third element is [1, 2, 3, 4]; the forth element is [4, 3, reverse[1, 2, 3, 4]]

Comment: @lurker why did you delete your answer, it solved the task :)

Comment: Um... because your comment to my answer was *not exactly...* :)

Comment: So the description of your predicate is: *`C` or the reverse of `C` contains subsequence consisting of reverse of `B` appended to `A` starting at an odd position in `C`*? I'm just trying to understand what `fib-list` means. It's making my brain hurt.

Comment: @lurker Instead of `my-append(C1, _, C);` it should be: `(my-append(C1, _, C);
        (my-reverse(C1, C2), my-append(_, C2, C)))`

Comment: Please use a `_` in place of `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking the problem and using Prolog imperatively, using it like you would the C language or other imperative languages.

Start by describing your predicate. Your `fib-list(A, B, C)` is saying that *`C` begins with the reverse of `B` appended to `A`*. So just write that:

```
fib-list(A, B, C) :-
    my-reverse(B, B1),          % B1 is reverse of B
    my-append(A, B1, C1),       % C1 is reverse of B (B1) appended to A
    my-append(C1, _, C).        % C is something/anything appended to C1
                                %   (C begins with C1)
```

Comment: there is a case when C contains reversed C1. I got your idea. Thank you

Comment: @bob_saginowski I think I "C" what you mean... :)